# после билда игры не работает клик мыши

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть скрипт стрельбы. В юнити он хорошо работал, но в забилденой игре он перестал реагировать на нажатия мыши.

я пробовал изменять `Input.GetMouseButton(0))` на `Input.GetButton("Fire1")`, но мои попытки не увенчались успехом

```
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetMouseButton(0)) && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            potrons = 30;
        }
        text.text = potrons.ToString() + "/30";
    }

    void Shoot()
    {


        RaycastHit hit;
        if (potrons >= 1)
        {
            _audioSource.PlayOneShot(shotSFX);
            muzzleFlash.Play();
            potrons--;

            if (Physics.Raycast(_cam.transform.position, _cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
            {
                Debug.Log("есть пробитие " + hit.collider);

                GameObject impact = Instantiate(hitEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
                Destroy(impact, 2f);

                if (hit.rigidbody != null)
                {
                    hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * force);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хоть бы написали, какая платформа.

Comment: PC, mac & linux standalone